# How can i read a csv file from a string while i compiled from info in an email?

Tags: python, string, csv

Im looking to access a csv file from a string which i have compiled from contents in python from an outlook email  and some pre defined things.

Basically the file location gets defined below as save_file_path but when i try to use read_csv to look at the data in python i get an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'attachment_final'

How can i resolve this?

```
import win32com.client
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data_final=str()

#Define Save Outlook Attachments Function
def save_outlook_attachments(folder_name,subject_line,save_location):
    outlook_application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    outlook_mailbox =outlook_application.Folders.Item(1) 
    messages = outlook_mailbox.Items
#this is your default mailbox. if you have multiple mailboxes in outlook try increasing this 
number (2,3,4 etc.)

    #Finds the correct Outlook Folder by searching for a folder that is equal to folder_name
    for folder in outlook_mailbox.Folders:
        if folder.Name == folder_name:
            found_folder = folder
            print('Folder Searched:' + found_folder.Name)

    #Sorts all emails in folder by date (descending)
    folder_emails = found_folder.Items
    folder_emails.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

    #Looks for correct email by searching for an email containing subject_line 
    for message in folder_emails:
        if subject_line in message.Subject and message.Unread: #If exact subject_line match is 
needed, switch "in" to "=="
            print('Found email with subject '+ message.Subject + ' sent on ' + 
message.SentOn.strftime('%m-%d-%y'))
            found_email = message
            break
        
    #Gets email attachment from email and saves to file location
    num_email_attachments = len([x for x in found_email.attachments])+1
    for attachment_num in range(1, num_email_attachments):
        attachment = found_email.attachments.Item(attachment_num)
        attachment_name = str(attachment)
        print('Attachment Number ' + str(attachment_num) +' - File Name : '+attachment_name)
        save_file_path = os.path.join (save_location,attachment_name)
        attachment.SaveAsFile(save_file_path)
        print('Attachment ' + str(attachment) +" saved to " + save_file_path)
    
        print(save_file_path)
    
    
        data_5=save_file_path.strip()
        data_final=data_5
    
            print(data_final)
    
    
#Define Variables
folder_name = 'Inbox'
subject_line = 'Subject' #case senstive, must contain phrase 
save_location = r'Z:\Test'
#the r before the file location is not a typo! It helps format the code correctly.


#Run Function
save_outlook_attachments(folder_name,subject_line,save_location)


df=pd.read_csv(data_final,sep=';',header=None)
df.to_excel (r'Z:\Test\XXXXX.xlsx', index = None, header=0)
print(df)


#initialze the excel writer
writer = pd.read_csv(data_final, sep=';', header=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'Z:\Test\Accruals.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Comment: is the file actually saved?

Comment: `data_final` is local to the `save_outlook_attachments()` function, you can't use it when you call `pd.read_csv()` outside the function.

Comment: I don't see where the filename `attachment_final` is coming from. `data_final` should still be the empty string you initialized it with.

Comment: @AndrewRyan yes the file is saved

Comment: @Barmar do you know how i would get around that and add it to the function? also where do you see attachment_final?

Comment: Use `global data_final` in the function. And I see `attachment_final` in the error message: `No such file or directory: 'attachment_final'`

Comment: Thanks! i just need to define data_final thatway at the top of the code? and, sorry about that my error message is getting the following: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your help, got my script to work!